# Deserialize multiple json object into c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

[image: Json response -Image]I'm trying to deserialize a json string into c# objects

**Json**

"{"TotalResulCount":

[{"ResultCount":1}],

"SearchResults":[{"ID":1,"LPWLastName":"","LPWFirstName":"","LPWLicenseNumber1":"","LPWLicenseTitle":"Clinical Genetic Molecular Biologist Scientist","LPWLicenseStatusCategory":"Active","LPWLicensee":"","LPWLicenseNumber2":"","LPWLicenseTypeDescription":"(CGMBS) Clinical Genetic Molecular Biologist Scientist","LPWLicenseType":"MTP","LPWIssueDate":"11/21/2013","LPWApprovalDate":"11/15/2019","LPWExpirationDate":"11/19/2021"}]}"

I Converted into classes by using https://json2csharp.com/

**Model classes**

```
  public class TotalResulCount
    {
        public int ResultCount { get; set; }
     

    }
        public class SearchResult
        {

            //public int ResultCount { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string LPWLastName { get; set; }
            public string LPWFirstName { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicenseNumber1 { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicenseTitle { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicenseStatusCategory { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicensee { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicenseNumber2 { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicenseTypeDescription { get; set; }
            public string LPWLicenseType { get; set; }
            public string LPWIssueDate { get; set; }
            public string LPWApprovalDate { get; set; }
            public string LPWExpirationDate { get; set; }
        }

    public class Root
    {

        public List<TotalResulCount> totalResulCounts { get; set; }
       public List<SearchResult> searchResults { get; set; }

    }
```

**I tried this approach**
1.Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);

I am unable to Deserialize the json objects in to c# objects can you please guide me and let me know appropriate way to deserialize josn objects to c#

**error**
Error converting value

1. "{"TotalResulCount":[{"ResultCount":1}],"SearchResults":[{"ID":1,"LPWLastName":"BOORGULA","LPWFirstName":"SMITHA","LPWLicenseNumber1":"MTP-00000453","LPWLicenseTitle":"Clinical Genetic Molecular Biologist Scientist","LPWLicenseStatusCategory":"Active","LPWLicensee":"SMITHA BOORGULA","LPWLicenseNumber2":"MTP 00000453","LPWLicenseTypeDescription":"(CGMBS) Clinical Genetic Molecular Biologist Scientist","LPWLicenseType":"MTP","LPWIssueDate":"11/21/2013","LPWApprovalDate":"11/15/2019","LPWExpirationDate":"11/19/2021"}]}" to type 'CDPHPlugIn.PlugInClass+Root'. Path '', line 1, position 584.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so please edit your question and add the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chang this

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);
```

To this

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: what error are you getting? Aren't you accidentely putting " at the start and at the end of the json? 
My code worked when I tried to load your json https://ctrlv.cz/0IGg

Comment: did you took classes in List ?

Comment: It is coming dynamically with " quotes

Comment: then you should remove them
json starts with { and ends with }  no quotes at the begining or at the end

Comment: thank you its working @Jan Skala I removed " " quotes and \ slash its Working Now